# Developing iAd supported app for client

Tags: ios, iad

I've been asked to build an iAd supported app for a client.

In order to collect whatever revenue there might be from the iAds, will the app need to be submitted under an account owned by them? (they'll need to create one, since they're not in the app business)

Or can I submit the app under my account and redirect the revenue somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should submit the app under their own name. Not only will that mean that the app appears to be owned by them (rather than you) in iTunes, but it means that they will be able to specify their own bank account details. This in no way prevents you from helping them complete the process.

There is no automatic ability to redirect the revenue. You'd have to create a contract and do it yourself. That's obviously out of scope for a technical Q&A site.